# Cosmos gremlin performance issue with query

Tags: gremlin, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

I am trying to run this query below but get a timeout issue.  Where is the inefficiency here?

```
   g.V().hasLabel('RiskLibrary','name','General 
Business','active','1').as('lib').select('lib').
outE('CONTAINS_RISK').select('lib').project('Risk 
Library','Risks').by('name').by(out('CONTAINS_RISK').project('Name',     
'Description','Impacts','Causes').by('name').by('description').
by(both('IMPACTS').project('name').by('name').fold()).
by(both('CAUSES').project('name').by('name').fold()).fold())
```

Answer (score 1):

Something about your traversal seems incorrect. For starters `hasLabel()` looks like it's being called with arguments that aren't labels. I assume the traversal should be:

```
g.V().has('RiskLibrary', 'name', 'General Business').has('active', '1').as('lib').
      select('lib').
      outE('CONTAINS_RISK').
      select('lib').
      project('Risk Library', 'Risks').
        by('name').
        by(out('CONTAINS_RISK').
           project('Name', 'Description', 'Impacts', 'Causes').
             by('name').
             by('description').
             by(both('IMPACTS').
                project('name').by('name').
                fold()).
             by(both('CAUSES').
                project('name').by('name').
                fold()).
             fold())
```

If that is correct then I'd wonder what the purpose of the traversal is exactly. As it stands right now I would expect it to `project('Risk Library', 'Risks')` for every single `outE('CONTAINS_RISK')`. You will get the same output for each of those edges as you `select('lib')` which grabs the original `Vertex` from which you traversed from. If you didn't intend that, you could imagine some significant query cost for performing the hefty `project('Risk Library', 'Risks')` over and over and over again.

Assuming the rest of your traversal is correct, I think you just need to get rid of the step label of `as('lib')` and the lines up to `project('Risk Library', 'Risks')`, thus:

```
g.V().has('RiskLibrary', 'name', 'General Business').has('active', '1').
      project('Risk Library', 'Risks').
        by('name').
        by(out('CONTAINS_RISK').
           project('Name', 'Description', 'Impacts', 'Causes').
             by('name').
             by('description').
             by(both('IMPACTS').
                project('name').by('name').
                fold()).
             by(both('CAUSES').
                project('name').by('name').
                fold()).
             fold())
```

That said, this may yet be an expensive traversal to execute depending on how many "IMPACTS" and "CAUSES" edges exist for each opposing vertex of the "CONTAINS_RISK" edge.

Comment: Thanks Stephen.  So, a final question, how do we filter based on a property of the 'CONTAINS_RISK' edge?

Comment: change `out('CONTAINS_RISK')` to `outE('CONTAINS_RISK').has('property', value).inV()`